# How to hide-show a modal only in one resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Have two component. The first have an `ng-click` and call the modal with the second component, everything works fine. What the problem is the modal should only be opened in 768 resolution...

Already try with media queries but no success..

Thanks!

here is code:

*parent.html*:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" ng-click="$ctrl.openModal()">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 benefit-parenthood">
        <div class="description">
            <p class='title'>lorem impsun title</p>
            <p class="area">
                <i class="fa fa-cookie-bite cookie-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class="area-item">lorem impsum</span>
            </p>
            <p class="area-mobile">lalala</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 container-image">
        <div class="partner-brand">
            <img src="app/assets/greyimg.png" class="partner-avatar">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*parent.component.js* :

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('parenthoodBenefit')
    .component('parenthoodBenefitComponent', {
      bindings: {},
      templateUrl: 'app/parenthood-benefit/parenthood.html',
      controller: parenthoodBenefitCtrl
    })    

  function parenthoodBenefitCtrl($scope, $uibModal) {
    this.openModal = function () {

      $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/modal-benefit/modal.html',
        size: 'lg',
        controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

          $scope.ok = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.close();
          };

          $scope.cancel = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          };
        }
      }).result.then(function () { }, function (res) { })
    };
  }
}());
```

*modal.html* :

```
<i class="fa fa-times icon-close" aria-hidden="true"  ng-click="ok()" ></i>
<access-detail-component></access-detail-component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `this.openModal()` method check  `if( $(window).width() > 767 ) { open modal.....}`

Comment: Thanks @piyush jain i try it and didn t work, but i use `$window.innerWidth <= 768` and works fine, do you think its a good way? thanks!

Comment: Ya .. you can use this approach. It mean uibModal open method won't be call if width is greater than 768px

Answer (score 0):

1.Get the width of window as you did and simply disable the click 
In Controller 
$scope.width=$window.innerWidth <= 768? false: true;

2.In html add ng-disabled="width" to respective div

This may better approach

Comment: Hi @swapnil kakade thanks!, i try and it works, but only works if i refresh the browser, its not dinamical..  if the modal is open in 768 and i change to bigger resolution the modal still there.. i mean, I do not know what to put in the else part...

Answer (score 0):

1.Updated answer - Add below function in your controller 
                 - This will get updated width if width changes

```
    angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){

     if($window.innerWidth <= 768){

      $scope.width =false;

       }else{ 

       //to disable click of open modal
       $scope.width =true;

       //then close your modal forcefully
       $uibModalInstance.close();

       //Run digest
       $scope.$digest();
    });
```

2.In html add ng-disabled="width" to respective div